# Google OAuth frustration

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to user Google's OAuth so that users of my app can sign in with their Google accounts. Unfortunately, when I use the code that they give me:

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "... Client ID ..."
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
```

It asks for the Reversed Client ID. But when I put that in, it asks for the other. And so on, vice versa. Can anyone tell what's going on?

- Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "It asks for the Reversed Client ID. But when I put that in, it asks for the other.", it would be great to see your exact error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [clientID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#add620bc77ecb9f7055be924c9005e038) property in your code should be set to regular (non-reversed) client ID.

The reversed client id is used as a URL scheme, and should be setup as per [Add URL schemes to your project](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#add_url_schemes_to_your_project). The URL scheme configuration is the *only* place you reference the reversed client ID.